# IAR Embedded Workbench and Custom Build

Tags: ide, build-process, iar

I have a project in IAR Embedded Workbench that works fine. In this project there is a source file (webpages.c) that is automatically created by another tool. This tool creates the file webpages.c starting from the files located in the specified folder webpages (so one file is generated starting from a set of files).

I want to configure the project in IAR in such a way, before the building process, the tool is automatically run if a file in the webpages folder is changed since the last build.

I configured a pre-build step and it really works with a Rebuild All. But if I change just a file in the webpages folder and issue a Make command, IDE thinks the project is up-to-date and doesn't start building.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

> > Can't you add them as files to your project under a separate group ?

Then, right-click the options for the group, select custom build, check "override inherited settings" and fill in the commands for the custom build step.